# Runtime error 1004 "range of object_worksheet failed

Tags: excel, vba

Want to use a cell change to run this code: get a runtime error.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler '<--| be sure to catch any error and enable   events handling back
Select Case Target.Address

    Case "$F$16"
       'Recalculate as necessary
       For counter = 1 To range("F16").Value
         Debug.Print counter;
        amount = range("F13").Value + (range("F13").Value * 0.15)
       Next
       range("F17").Value = amount

End Select
ErrorHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True '<--| enable events handling

End Sub
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: this is wrong `range("(F13")` should be `range("F13")`

Comment: Missing `On Error Goto ErrorHandler`...

Comment: I edited the corrections and now no runtime error but it isn't looping through my for loop. "debug.print 1"

Comment: You're still missing the fix on the `+ (range("(F23").Value ...` Or is that corrected in your workbook? Also, add `Option Explicit` to the very top (even above `Priavet Sub ...` to force all variables to be declared.  You should add `Dim counter as Long`, and just quickly try `For counter = 1 to 5` and see if it loops then.  Also, while debugging, I suggest turning *off* (comment out) the error handling.  Also, I *think* `counter` is a reserved word. Change that to `i` for now and see if it works.

Comment: oh BruceWayne, I only changed it on one. It was still wrong. That fixed Everything. The for is looping properly and the Cell filled in with the right number. I still used  debug.Print Counter; and it also displayed the numbers sequentially. Crazy how one can look and look at syntax and not see it. Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments, this should work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler   '<--| be sure to catch any error and enable   events handling back
Dim i As Long

Select Case Target.Address

Case "$F$16"
    'Recalculate as necessary
    For i = 1 To Range("F16").Value
        Debug.Print i
        Range("F17").Value = Range("F13").Value + (Range("F13").Value * 0.15)
    Next i

End Select
ErrorHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True    '<--| enable events handling

End Sub
```

Comment: Spoke too soon. I edited my first post to reflect that I  assigned the calculation to a variable named amount. then assigned it to F17 after the for loop. F17 displays only the calculation after the first iteration. 172.50 ???

Comment: @geddeca oh wait, just realized you don't loop anything.  What's the lop supposed to do? Are you looking to loop through cells? Currently, the loop is pointless.

Comment: I want it to keep adding the 15% of the original amount for as many iterations (years) as are selected in F16. Then after that assign the final amount to F17.

Comment: Select Case Target.Address
    
        Case "$F$16"
           'Recalculate as necessary
           For counter = 1 To range("F16").Value
             Debug.Print counter;
            amount = range("F13").Value + (range("F13").Value * 0.15)
           Next
           range("F17").Value = amount
    End Select

Comment: OH, I see that it is only assigning the first iteration to amount. I think that I need to write amount = amount + range("F13").Value + (range("F13").Value * 0.15) or something like this. so that it keeps the 15% already added and then does it again and again.

Comment: OK Figured it out. Wish I could delete some of my silly comments but too late. I had to assign F13 Value to amount before the loop and then let it add the 15% to amount as many times as chosen.